# ActionMailer string encoding

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, encoding, utf-8, actionmailer

Been banging my head against this for a while. I have this string:

```
[18] pry(main)> p.title
=> "Human meat – Wesker and Son butchers at Smithfield Market"
[19] pry(main)> p.title.encoding
=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
[20] pry(main)> p.title.force_encoding("ascii").encode
=> "Human meat ��� Wesker and Son butchers at Smithfield��Market"
```

This is called in my email template through ActionMailer, and--as you can probably guess--shows up in my email client equally garbled:

```
<a href=3D"http://localhost:3000/stuff/12072" =
style=3D"color: #D84D3F; text-decoration: none;">Human meat =EF=BF=BD=EF=BF=
=BD=EF=BF=BD=EF=BF=BD=EF=BF=BD=EF=BF=BD=EF=BF=BD=EF=BF=BD=EF=BF=BD Wesker=
 and Son butchers at Smithfield=EF=BF=BD=EF=BF=BD=EF=BF=BD=EF=BF=BD=EF=BF=
=BD=EF=BF=BDMarket</a>
```

Despite my headers seemingly setting the `Content-Type` correctly to `UTF-8`:

```
----==_mimepart_5082362f64bbe_36cb3feb84c5a7386303d
Date: Fri, 19 Oct 2012 22:27:11 -0700
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-ID: <5082362f6a388_36cb3feb84c5a738632e9@MacBook-Air.local.mail>
```

I've [read](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) [lots](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/05/05/ruby-1-9-encodings-a-primer-and-the-solution-for-rails/) on the subject, and despite being very informative, I still have no clue how to get rid of these pesky question marks. What do I have to do to get rid of them (with `ruby 1.9.3-p194`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I wasn't aware we were using the `premailer` gem to parse our emails. There seems to be an inconsistency in RubyGems in that my system reports I have `premailer 1.7.3`, yet my `lib/premailer/adapter/nokogiri.rb` does not match the one in the github repo, for the same version.

I've updated my `Gemfile` to use the github version and voila! UTF-8 characters again in my emails!